# Is it possible to get the name of the declaring scope of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable at some point of a JavaScript code. Now I would like to get the name of the function (aka scope) where that variable was declared. So for example if that variable is a field of an oject, I would like to get the name of the object's type.

Consider the following code:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.name = "MyName";
  this.age = 20;
}

var myVariable = new window.MyClass();
alert(getDeclaringScope(myVariable)) // should alert 'window'
alert(getDeclaringScope(myVariable.name)) // should alert 'MyClass
```

Is there any way to implement the `getDeclaringScope` function?

UPDATE

I wanted to use some technic like this to access to access a kind of "static" variable where meta information is stored for knockoutjs observable. A farly simplified example:

```
var META = {};
META["MyClass"] = {};
META["MyClass"]["MyArray"] = { ElementType: "MyOtherClass" };

function MyClass() {
  this.MyArray = ko.observableArray();
}
function MyOtherClass() {
  this.name = "a";
}

ko.observableArray.fn.addFromPlainObjects = function(plainItems) {
  var elemType = .... here I wanted to get "MyOtherClass" from the META global variable
  // create MyOtherClass and map the plain items to it... etc.
}
```

Comment: Generally it's not, as you shouldn't need it

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you're probably right, I wanted to implement something fancy in our JS framework, but I think I will work it around.

Comment: Given the way variables work in JS, I don't think that would be possible at all (For instance, what about anonymous functions etc.). If you can explain why you need it, maybe we can suggest an alternative approach

Comment: There are some workarounds to at least do something with `arguments.callee` etc. but that's just bad practice and should be avoided like the plague. Generally you shouldn't need to get the name of an instanciated class, and the execution context can be accessed with `this` etc.

Comment: I've added my motivation. But anyway I see that there's no way of doing this, so I will find a simple workaround, for example will extend the observable Array with an elementType property so it will know what type of elements should be in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The object has a reference to its constructor, but the constructor could be referenced from many objects, not just `window` in this case.  It could be accessed directly with a variable (as opposed to a property):

```
var MyClass = window.MyClass;
var foo = new MyClass();
```

You can create a back-reference explicitly in your object model, as constructor functions are objects.

```
window.MyClass.backref = window;
```

Though this is most likely not what you want.  I suspect you have a misunderstanding regarding what the scope of a variable is;  a variable scope has nothing to do with object properties.  As such, there is no notion of "declaring scope" that represents the object and object property from which a variable reference was retrieved, as you seem to conceptualize it.

Comment: Yes I think you're right, I'm working too much with .NET and its reflection framework, where you have PropertyInfos which will tell you what the declaring type is. But those cannot be retrieved from a simple variable value either, I mixed up "variables" and "variable infos". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof and constructor:

Eg.

```
    myVariable instanceof MyClass; //true

    myVariable.constructor;
   // returns 
    function MyClass() {
      this.name = "MyName";
      this.age = 20;
    }
```

Check: [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) and [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: Yes I know about them, but I don't know how these could help me in my case. My problem seems to be much more fancy.